# Change the selected index of listBox after every 2 seconds using threading

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, timer

I want to change the index of selected index of listbox after every two seconds.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listBox1.Items.Add("A");
    listBox1.Items.Add("B");
    listBox1.Items.Add("C");
    listBox1.Items.Add("D");
    listBox1.Items.Add("E");
    listBox1.Items.Add("F");
}

public void SelectEvery2Sec()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer=new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        timer.Start();
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
        catch{}

        if(i == listBox1.Items.Count -1)
            i = 0;
    }
}
```

But we can not stop main Thread.Then Application run but I could not see GUI. It is not correct way so I am try next way i.e. Another Thread.

Then I will create a new Thread but cross access of thread is not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I will create a new Thread but cross access of thread is not allowed?

Correct. You cannot access UI controls from a non-UI thread. You will get an exception if you try.

Multiple threads are not necessarily the right solution in every case. For this situation, a timer control might be simpler—the one you want is called [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx).

Alternatively, you could use a [`BackgroundWorker` component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). All you have to do is add it to your form at design time and it takes care of all the dirty work for you. There's a great sample on the MSDN page.

Do note that [`Thread.Sleep` is the sign of a poorly-designed program](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx). If you ever find yourself writing that in your code, you're doing it wrong. There's almost certainly a better way.

This type of question gets asked an awful lot on Stack Overflow. You can find more information by performing a search.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `Timer` or `BackgroundWorker`. For `Timer`, set the `Interval` to 2 secs. For `BackgroundWorker` use `RunWorkerAsync`.

For `cross thread access issue` use

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void Invoke(this Control control, Action action)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired) control.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(action), null);
        else action.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Your old code

```
listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
```

will become

```
listBox1.Invoke(() => { listBox1.SelectedIndex = i; });
```

Comment: You won't need to `Invoke` if you use a `Timer`. That's sort of the point. The timer will raise events on the UI thread, which is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Set `Interval` of you timer object to 2000 ms, do not make main thread sleep.

You can hanndle the Timer Elapsed event and update the control.

UPDATE:

For making it by two threads, raise an event in second thread every 2000 ms and wire a method in you Form to it. In that method you can change the controls of your form.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` use a `System.Threading.Timer`. This can be run in a worker thread.

Have the timer timeout event handler call a function to change the `ListBox.SelectedItem`, be sure to check `Invoke.Required` on changing the ListBox selected item as yo umay need to `Invoke` it.

Comment: You will definitely need to use `Invoke` (or `BeginInvoke`) to interact with UI controls from a non-UI thread. But putting all the glue together yourself is rather pointless when you could just use a `BackgroundWorker` to handle it all.